# Dependent parameter not updated in child build in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have two build configurations: build A that has an Artifact dependency on build B.  In build B I set two configuration parameters: `image-name` and `tag`, tag value being B's `%build.number%`.  In project A I use `dep.B_ID.image-name` and `dep.B_ID.tag`.  Build A is correcty triggered when B creates the artifact and both parameters are passed fine from B to A, however tag is not updated to the latest value of B's build number.  In other words, I have B at build number 18, and B's `tag` is correctly set to 18 (printed in build log), however build A uses an earlier value of tag - 16.  If I trigger build A manually, it picks up the latest tag number from B just fine.  This is happening in two different projects.  TeamCity version   2017.2.2 (build 50909).  Any pointers appreciated.

**Update**

Currently every time build A is triggered by build B, it picks up *previous* artifact from build B. In other words, build B is at id 23, so artifact 23 should be used by build A.  However build A is using artifact 22 instead.  This is consistent across projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to TeamCity Enterprise 2019.1.4 (build 66526) and the issue went away.